# SAS not reaching conditional clause despite conditions being met

Tags: sas

This is my first day with SAS.

I use the following code to try to create a flag which identifies when a row of my data set has the property that the field `a` (character) remains the same as the corresponding field in the previous row, and the field `b` (character) is different than the corresponding field of the previous row:

```
DATA WORK.temp1; 
SET WORK.temp2;

RETAIN PREV_a
            PREV_b;

IF( (PREV_a = a) AND (PREV_b NE b)) THEN DO; 
    FLAG = "Y";
    END;
ELSE 
    FLAG = "N";


PREV_a = a;
PREV_b = b;
RUN;
```

The result is that the flag always has the value "N", even in cases where it should have the value "Y". I tested the code on a data set which I constructed manually in a preceding DATA step and it worked there, so I'm sure the logic and syntax are okay (after all, this is incredibly simple).

Thus I conclude that there is some special SAS knowledge which I lack which explains why this might not work in cases where the DATA is SET from a previous node in the project flow.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: One question: are you 100% sure `prev_a` and `prev_b` don't exist on the `work.temp2` dataset?  They have to be not present on this dataset or it won't work.

Comment: @Joe I am sure, but nevertheless I pointed the program to a newly created copy of `work.temp2` called `work.temp3` and that seemed to get me part of the way to where I need to be (see my response to Robert Penridge for details. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Looks fine to me.  In my test data below, only row D has the flag set to 'Y'.  What would you be expecting the output to be?

Some test data:

```
data temp2;
  input row $ a b;
datalines;
a 1 2
b 2 3
c 3 4
d 3 5
e 3 5 
f 4 5
g 5 6
h 7 8
i 7 8
;
run;
```

Your code (note - I've added an `output` statement to explicitly write the contents of the variables to the dataset prior to the final assignment of prev_a and prev_b.  This makes it easier to see what is happening in the if statements):

```
DATA WORK.temp1; 
SET WORK.temp2;

RETAIN PREV_a
            PREV_b;

IF( (PREV_a = a) AND (PREV_b NE b)) THEN DO; 
    FLAG = "Y";
    END;
ELSE 
    FLAG = "N";
output; /* ADDED */

PREV_a = a;
PREV_b = b;
RUN;
```

Comment: I think I am getting closer to a solution. Following Joe's point, I pointed the program to a newly created intermediate data set work.temp3, even though prev_a and prev_b did not exist in work.temp2. This at least produced more than just N's for the flag, but the Y's occur always one row before where they should. Thus in your example the Y would occur at row C. There is a PROC SORT which is called immediately before the data step which sorts by a descending by a separate time variable, but that should be ok. I tried changing descending to ascending, but SAS doesn't recognize that keyword. Thx!